# Extent in ArcGlobe

Tags: arcobjects, 3d-analyst, extents, arcglobe

Does anyone know if it's possible to get an Envelope/Extent in ArcGlobe based upon what's visible on the globe.

For instance, I'm looking to be able to zoom in over the state of Pennsylvania and get an Envelope back with that part of the globe?  That way I could have a boundary-box/envelope of what's currently visible....

I've looked at GlobeDisplay.CurrentViewer.Camera

I've looked at Camera.Target.QueryCoords(out x, out y)

I've looked at GlobeDisplay.ActiveViewera.Camera.QueryEnvelope

None of these seem to work.  If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/java/api/arcobjects/com/esri/arcgis/globecore/IGlobeViewUtilProxy.html#queryVisibleGeographicExtent%28com.esri.arcgis.geometry.IEnvelope%29

There's the answer.

QueryVisibleGeographicExtent - pass in an empty Envelope Class and it returns the extent.